# Bash pattern string conversion

Tags: bash

Let's say we have the following string:

```
aabbccddeeff
```

How can I transform this string to:

```
AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
```

Can it be done with regex or something more easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `&` at the replacement part to refer all the matched characters.

```
$ echo 'aabbccddeeff' | sed 's/.*/\U&/;s/\(..\)/\1:/g;s/:$//'
AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
```

Comment: `sed 's/../\U&:/g;s/:$//'` is more direct, but given GNU sed, yes, that's the way.

Comment: or `sed 's/\(..\)/\U\1:/g;s/:$//'`

Comment: or `perl -pe 's/(..)/\U$1:/g;s/:$//'`

Answer (score 2):

A Bash-only solution, as a one-liner:

```
str=${str^^*} ; for (( i=0 ; i<${#str} ; i+=2 )) ; do [[ i -ne 0 ]] && echo -n ":" ; echo -n ${str:i:2} ; done ; echo
```

and expanded:

```
# convert string to uppercase:
str=${str^^*}

# loop through each pair of characters:
for (( i=0 ; i<${#str} ; i+=2 ))
do 
  # if it is not the first pair, add a leading colon:
  [[ i -ne 0 ]] && echo -n ":"
  # print this part of the string:
  echo -n ${str:i:2}
done
# add a newline:
echo
```

Please read this as a demonstration of what Bash can do. Code like this is not portable and probably a little less maintainable than other solutions. It offers better performance, but this will not often be an issue.

Comment: Or: `str=aabbccddeeff a=(); while IFS= read -r -N2 b; do a+=("$b"); done <<< "$str"; IFS=: eval 'printf "%s\n" "${a[*]^^}"'`.